# HTML Refresh page after form submitting to python code

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have an HTML code which has a "download" button that makes a file download in page through GET to a python code, the thing is this page has a refresh rate of 5 seconds and works well but as soon as I click the download button and file is download the page stops refreshing.

what can I do to fix it?

HTML :

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
<style>
mark {
       background-color: grey;
        color: white;
}
</style>
<title>{{client}}</title>
        
        <form target="_parent" method="get" action="download_file" style="display: inline;">
        <h4><mark>{{client}}</mark></h4>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <button  onclick="openNav()">download</button>
                    <input type=hidden name="client" value="{{client}}">
                    <input type=hidden name="reason" value="{{reason}}">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Python:

```
@app.route("/download_file", methods=["GET"])
def download_file():
#a lot of code to get the file
    response = flask.Response(output, mimetype="zip", headers={"Content-disposition":"attachment; filename="+  randomName + ".zip"})
    return response
```

Have tried adding the `onclick` of the button the `"window.location.reload();"` doesnt do anything,
it waits until file done downloading and the page losing its refresh option until i do it manually using F5 on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed button from :

```
<button  onclick="openNav()">download</button>
```

To:

```
<button onclick="window.setTimeout(function () {  window.location.reload();}, 10000)">download</button>
```

Solved it for me.
And i removed the

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Because i needed page to refresh after form submitting